# Auto increment on duplicate?

Tags: mysql

I am facing problem while my query is executing. While I am doing any changes my existing data and after that while I am inserting new data at that time db's id is incremented by no of time i have updated previous data.

```
query = "insert into emp_mst(emp_code, emp_sbu, emp_name)"
                    + " value(?,?,?)"
                    + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `emp_name`=?";   
conn = CloudConnection.getConnection();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setString(1, e.getEmp_code());
        ps.setString(2, e.getEmp_sbu());
        ps.setString(3, e.getEmp_name());


        ps.setString(4, e.getEmp_name());

        ps.executeUpdate();
```

and my unique column is emp_code.

Comment: So why is it a problem?

Comment: I want not to increment id while updating existing data!

Comment: Any technical reason behind "I want not to"? What's wrong with non-consecutive primary key values?

Comment: technically there's no problem at all to my application, but I was just queerest about why this is happening so. I just want to know about is it behaviour of insert on update query or it's bug of query written by me?

Comment: It is expected behaviour

Comment: thank zerkms fro quick response